# Pros / Cons to Different Binding Approaches using MVVM and RIA Services

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, mvvm-light

I have been building an application, which uses the LoadOperation's Entities to return an IEnumerable which becomes the source of a CollectionViewSource in my View Model.  I am now discovering the potential pitfall to this approach, when adding Entities in my Silverlight client, I cannot see these entities, unless I either submit the New Entity, then reload, or Maintain a separate collection of items, which I am binding to.

What I really see as my options are:

1. Add an ObservableCollection to use as the Source of the CollectionViewSource property in my ViewModel - this way I can add to both the DomainContext and the ObservableCollection at the same time to keep the collections in sync.
2. Change the Binding to the EntitySet directly, and add a filtering event handler to provide the filtering on the CollectionViewSource.

If anyone has tips or thoughts about pros/cons of each, I would greatly appreciate it.  In particular, I am wondering, if there are performance and/or programming benefits in favor of one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am taking this one approach at a time.  First, I am going to show a point of reference to dicuss this with, then I will highlight the different changes necessary to support each methodology.

The basis for my demo is a single, authenticated domain service which returns a single entity of Resource.  I will expose 4 commands (save, undo, add, and delete), plus a Collection, and a Property to hold the SelectedResource.

2 Different classes implement this interface (1 for blending, 1 for production).  The production is the only one I will discuss here.  Notice the action(lo.Entities) in the GetMyResources function:

```cs
public class WorkProvider
{
    static WorkContext workContext;
    public WorkProvider()
    {
        if (workContext == null)
            workContext = new WorkContext();
    }
    public void AddResource(Resource resource)
    {
        workContext.Resources.Add(resource);
    }
    public void DelResource(Resource resource)
    {
        workContext.Resources.Remove(resource);
    }
    public void UndoChanges()
    {
        workContext.RejectChanges();
    }
    public void SaveChanges(Action action)
    {
        workContext.SubmitChanges(so =>
            {
                if (so.HasError)
                    // Handle Error
                    throw so.Error;
                else
                    action();
            }, null);
    }
    public void GetMyResources(Action<IEnumerable<Resource>> action)
    {
        var query = workContext.GetResourcesQuery()
            .Where(r => r.UserName == WebContext.Current.User.Name);
        workContext.Load(query, LoadBehavior.MergeIntoCurrent, lo =>
            {
                if (lo.HasError)
                    // Handle Error
                    throw lo.Error;
                else
                    action(lo.Entities);
            }, null);
    }
}
```

In the ViewModel, I have the following Implementation:

```cs
public class HomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    WorkProvider workProvider;
    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        workProvider = new WorkProvider();
    }

    // _Source is required when returning IEnumerable<T>
    ObservableCollection<Resource> _Source; 
    public CollectionViewSource Resources { get; private set; }
    void setupCollections()
    {
        Resources = new CollectionViewSource();
        using (Resources.DeferRefresh())
        {
            _Source = new ObservableCollection<Resource>();
            Resources.Source = _Source;
            Resources.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Title"));
            Resources.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Title", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            Resources.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Rate", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        }
    }
    void loadMyResources()
    {
        workProvider.GetMyResources(results =>
            {
                using (Resources.DeferRefresh())
                {
                    // This is required when returning IEnumerable<T>
                    _Source.Clear();
                    foreach (var result in results)
                    {
                        if (!_Source.Contains(result))
                            _Source.Add(result);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
    Resource _SelectedResource;
    public Resource SelectedResource
    {
        get { return _SelectedResource; }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedResource != value)
            {
                _SelectedResource = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedResource");
            }
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand CmdSave { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand CmdUndo { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand CmdAdd { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand CmdDelete { get; private set; }
    void setupCommands()
    {
        CmdSave = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                workProvider.SaveChanges(() =>
                    {
                        DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
                            {
                                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Saved");
                            });
                    });
            });
        CmdUndo = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                workProvider.UndoChanges();
                // This is required when returning IEnumerable<T>
                loadMyResources();
            });
        CmdAdd = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                Resource newResource = new Resource()
                {
                    ResourceID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Rate = 125,
                    Title = "Staff",
                    UserName = "jsmith"
                };
                // This is required when returning IEnumerable<T>
                _Source.Add(newResource);
                workProvider.AddResource(newResource);
            });
        CmdDelete = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            // This is required when returning IEnumerable<T>
            _Source.Remove(_SelectedResource);
            workProvider.DelResource(_SelectedResource);
        });
    }
}
```

The alternate method would involve changing the WorkProvider class as follows (notice the action(workContext.Resources) that is returned:

```cs
    public void GetMyResources(Action<IEnumerable<Resource>> action)
    {
        var query = workContext.GetResourcesQuery()
            .Where(r => r.UserName == WebContext.Current.User.Name);
        workContext.Load(query, LoadBehavior.MergeIntoCurrent, lo =>
            {
                if (lo.HasError)
                    // Handle Error
                    throw lo.Error;
                else
                    // Notice Changed Enumeration
                    action(workContext.Resources);
            }, null);
    }
```

And the changes to the viewmodel are as follows (notice the removal of the _Source ObservableCollection):

```cs
public class HomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    WorkProvider workProvider;
    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        workProvider = new WorkProvider();
    }

    public CollectionViewSource Resources { get; private set; }
    void setupCollections()
    {
        Resources = new CollectionViewSource();
        using (Resources.DeferRefresh())
        {
            Resources.Filter += (s,a) =>
                {
                    a.Accepted = false;
                    if (s is Resource)
                    {
                        Resource res = s as Resource;
                        if (res.UserName == WebContext.Current.User.Name)
                            a.Accepted = true;
                    }
                };
            Resources.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Title"));
            Resources.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Title", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            Resources.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Rate", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        }
    }
    void loadMyResources()
    {
        workProvider.GetMyResources(results =>
            {
                using (Resources.DeferRefresh())
                {
                    Resources.Source = results;
                }
            });
    }
    Resource _SelectedResource;
    public Resource SelectedResource
    {
        get { return _SelectedResource; }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedResource != value)
            {
                _SelectedResource = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedResource");
            }
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand CmdSave { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand CmdUndo { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand CmdAdd { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand CmdDelete { get; private set; }
    void setupCommands()
    {
        CmdSave = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                workProvider.SaveChanges(() =>
                    {
                        DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
                            {
                                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Saved");
                            });
                    });
            });
        CmdUndo = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                workProvider.UndoChanges();
                Resources.View.Refresh();
            });
        CmdAdd = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                Resource newResource = new Resource()
                {
                    ResourceID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Rate = 125,
                    Title = "Staff",
                    UserName = "jsmith"
                };
                workProvider.AddResource(newResource);
            });
        CmdDelete = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            workProvider.DelResource(_SelectedResource);
        });
    }
}
```

While the second approach definately requires adding the filter event handler in the configuration of the CollectionViewSource, and could be seen as filtering data 2 times (1 time at the server, and the second time by the CollectionViewSource), it does off the following benefits:  There is a single collection - which makes management of collection notifications simpler and easier.  The collection is the actual collection which will be submitted to the server, which makes managing adds/deletes simpler, since there are not opportunities for forgetting to add/remove entities from the correct collection to initiate the add/delete function when submitting back.

The one last thing I need to confirm is the following:  On a collectionviewsource, it is my understanding that you should use DeferRefresh() when making multiple changes that affect the view.  This just prevents unnecessary refreshes from occuring when internal changes may cause refreshes such as configuring sorting, grouping, etc.  It is also important to call .View.Refresh() when we expect the UI to process some update changes.  The .View.Refresh() is probably more important to note than the DeferRefresh(), since it actually causes a UI update, as opposed to a prevent unexpected UI updates.

I don't know if this will help others, but I hope so.  I definately spent some time working through these and trying to understand this.  If you have clarifications or other things to add, please feel free to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan, it might be worth your while to take a look through [this post on collection binding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/12/02/collection-binding-options-in-wcf-ria-services-sp1.aspx) (and some of the related ones). Your implementation is certainly a reasonable one, but I can see it wrestles with a few of the issues that have already been resolved at the framework level.